# Error in cabal-installing hspec

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I'm trying to install hspec, but I'm getting this:

```
$ cabal install hspec
Resolving dependencies...                                                                                                                                               
cabal: dependencies conflict: ghc-7.2.2 requires containers ==0.4.2.0 however                                                                                           
containers-0.4.2.0 was excluded because ghc-7.2.2 requires containers                                                                                                   
==0.4.1.0
```

What does this even mean?

Also, using ghc 7.2.2, cabal 10.2.

Comment: What is the output of `ghc-pkg check`?

Comment: Warning: haddock-interfaces: /home/clark/.cabal/share/doc/InternalLibrary4-0.2/html/InternalLibrary4.haddock doesn't exist or isn't a file
Warning: haddock-html: /home/clark/.cabal/share/doc/InternalLibrary4-0.2/html doesn't exist or isn't a directory
Warning: include-dirs: /usr/include/libpng14 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
Warning: include-dirs: /usr/include/libpng14 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
Warning: include-dirs: /usr/include/libpng14 doesn't exist or isn't a directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you somehow broke your GHC install.  GHC 7.2.2 [comes with](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.2/html/users_guide/release-7-2-1.html) containers-0.4.1.0 (the version of which is the same as for GHC 7.2.1).  It *might* be possible to fix it, but if the global package setup is broken then it would probably be easiest to re-install GHC.

What does `ghc-pkg list containers` say?

If `containers-0.4.2.2` is found only in the per-user install (i.e. the `/home/clark/.ghc/${arch}-${os}-7.2.2/package.conf.d` output), then `rm`'ing `/home/clark/.ghc/` and re-installing all the packages you installed with `cabal install` will fix it.

Comment: Output of `ghc-pkg list containers` => `/usr/lib/ghc-7.2.2/package.conf.d
   containers-0.4.1.0
/home/clark/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.2.2/package.conf.d
   containers-0.4.2.0
`

Comment: @ClarkGaebel: so you could try "ghc-pkg unregister containers-0.4.2.0" and see if that fixes it.

Comment: It says it would break a huge number of packages if I did. Should I --force it?

Comment: @ClarkGaebel Yes, then rebuild those packages.  You should *never* upgrade the boot libraries that come with GHC (base, containers, array, bytestring, etc.; Cabal is the only library that comes with GHC that you can safely install a newer version of in parallel).

Comment: I just did a full install of my system (`rm -rf .ghc .cabal`), reinstalled everything. Turns our there were two versions of containers installed thanks to a recent hashmap update. Thanks for your help! Have some bounty.